# Cargo Maven plugin Token Replacement

Tags: cargo, maven-cargo

I am using cargo-maven plugin and I am trying to use token replacement feature of the plugin. Somehow its not working for me. I think I dont know how to represent token so that cargo can replace it with the value. Here is my plugin config

```
<configfiles>  
    <configfile>  
        <file>src/main/resources/test.properties</file>  
    </configfile>  
</configfiles>  
<properties>  
    <dchome>/users/target</dchome>  
</properties>
```

Contents of my test.properties are as follows:

```
project.home = $dchome
```

It would be great if any one can show me an example of how to use token replacement of cargo plugin.

Thanks

Comment: I got the answer from cargo user groups. Here is the link http://old.nabble.com/Cargo-Token-Replacement-td31045897.html#a31046873

Comment: I think this is the updated link: http://cargo.996258.n3.nabble.com/Cargo-Token-Replacement-tp2065.html

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and came across this page while googling for a solution, so I figured I would post my resolution here in the hope it helps someone else.

The original poster was close to a solution - he just had to use a leading and trailing AT symbol (@) to denote the text he wanted to replace in his property file.

So, the solution is pretty straight-forward; instead of doing this in the test.properties file:

```
project.home = $dchome
```

He needed to do this instead:

```
project.home = @dchome@
```

Once that change was made the Cargo plugin was able to update the property file with the correct information from the "properties" section of the pom.